# Computing outer (tensor) product of cv::Mat in OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there a way to computer the outer product (**z** * transpose(**z**) for some column vector **z**) using the `cv::Mat` data structure in OpenCV?

I've checked [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) and there's no built in function. But I'm getting exceptions trying to use the standard matrix multiplication expression (*) with a vector of type `cv::Mat`.

Here's the (pseudo)code:

```
cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat::zeros(9, 1, CV_32SC1)
cv::Mat outerProduct = tmp * tmp.t();
```

The outer product calculation gives exceptions. (Yes I have actual values in the tmp matrix in my actual code, but this description gives more info about the data type being used)

Ideally, the `cv::Mat outerProduct` should end up as a 9x9 matrix.

I could do it using the scaling multiplication property of `cv::Mat` (i.e. repeat the column vector `tmp` by its dimensions, and for each column, scale the elements by the value in the index--[as in how you may solve this kind of multiplication by hand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#Definition_.28matrix_multiplication.29)):

```
cv::Mat outerProduct = cv::repeat(tmp, 1, 9);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    outerProduct.col(i) *= tmp.at<int>(i, 0);
}
```

...but it would be nice to have a better way if there is one.

Comment: int type is not supported for this, you need CV_32F or such

Comment: From [the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#multransposed): mulTransposed "can multiply not only floating-point matrices." See @beaker's answer below. He lists which types are supported. Integers are but only 8 and 16 bit types

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that while my answer is correct, [@kaanoner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33242361/1377097) gives better performance.

---

They sneak these methods in where you least expect. This one is in [Operations on Arrays](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) and it's called [mulTransposed](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#multransposed).

```
cv::Mat tmp = (Mat_<double>(9,1) << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
cv::Mat outerProduct;
mulTransposed(tmp, outerProduct, false);
```

The third parameter is `aTa`. If it's true, the method calculates a<sup>T</sup>a. If it's false, it calculates aa<sup>T</sup>.

Output is:

```
tmp = 
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]
outerProduct = 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18;
 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27;
 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36;
 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45;
 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54;
 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63;
 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72;
 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]
```

Looking through the source code, it appears that `CV_32S` is not supported by `mulTransposed`. Here are the source and destination types they specify:

```
(stype == CV_8U && dtype == CV_32F)
(stype == CV_8U && dtype == CV_64F)
(stype == CV_16U && dtype == CV_32F)
(stype == CV_16U && dtype == CV_64F)
(stype == CV_16S && dtype == CV_32F)
(stype == CV_16S && dtype == CV_64F)
(stype == CV_32F && dtype == CV_32F)
(stype == CV_32F && dtype == CV_64F)
(stype == CV_64F && dtype == CV_64F)
```

As this implies, the destination type is always a float type. Even when I specify a dtype of `CV_16S`, I get a matrix that's `CV_32F`.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I call that function on a `Mat` of type `CV_32SC1` I get an "unsupported format or combination of formats" error from OpenCV. I checked the docs and they specifically mention that mulTransposed "can multiply not only floating-point matrices." For me `tmp` is type `CV_32SC1`, but it still fails when I specify the type of the `outerProduct` `Mat`. Any ideas what's up?

Comment: Checking, but I'm seeing the same thing when I use `CV_32SC1` instead of `double`, even if I specify the `dtype` parameter as `CV_32SC1` or `-1`.

Comment: Strange... I'll have to poke around. Thanks again!

Comment: Wow. Just for kicks, try `CV_16SC1`. I'm looking through the code and there's no mention of `CV_32S`, only 16-bit integers.

Answer (score 3):

In my runs, the transpose and multiply method is twice as fast as than the single [mulTransposed](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#multransposed) function call.

```
Mat descriptor; //(1 rows x 192 cols, CV_32F)
Mat outerProduct;

// calculates outer products for 10000 different descriptors in a loop
mulTransposed(descriptor, outerProduct, true); // => takes 33 secs
outerProduct = descriptor.t()*descriptor; // => takes 14 secs
```

Comment: This is really interesting. One thing I noticed is that the input arrays must be floats, but that doesn't seem to be a very big restriction for such a performance gain. Good catch!